# Android SampleBrowserPlugin Installation failed

Tags: android, android-ndk, npapi, android-source

I am trying to install the samplebrowserplugin given in the android source code. As given here (https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/BrowserPlugin), I am able to follow it to the second step (`make SampleBrowserPlugin`). I have the .apk file now but when I try to install it using adb, all I get is

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

When I run logcat, among various messages, I see

```
DexOptZ: zip archive '/data/app/com.android.sampleplugin-1.apk' does not include classes.dex
```